# c++: std::minmax для массива arr[2]

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl

подскажите, можно ли в C++ с использованием функций STL сделать так:

```
arr[2] = {obj1, obj2};

arr = std::minmax(arr[0], arr[1], lambda);
```

понимаю, что для такой конструкции можно просто сделать собственный код:

```
if (!cmp(arr[0], arr[1]) {
    const auto tmp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[0];
}
```

но интересно, дает ли stl возможность "однострочно" делать такие операции, не создавая свой код

Comment: Это  алгоритм сортировки с  предикатом  `cmp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое не подойдет?

```
auto [m,M] = std::minmax(arr[0], arr[1], lambda);
```

Хотя

```
if (arr[0]>arr[1]) swap(arr[0],arr[1]);
```

пожалуй, короче :)

Comment: да, оба варианта подходят, спасибо, не привык что-то пока к `[]` конструкциям :)